# R move the cells of a dataframe to fill in empty cells

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

Is there a way in R to create a condition something like this:

For the following data, if in the first column the row is empty but other columns in that row are filled, then shift the row to left to fill in the first column.

For example, the actual data looks like this:

```
DIS1                
         area1  69284   178198  2.57
area2    9466   22586   2.39    NA
Total    78750  200784  2.55    NA
DIS2                
        area1   25008   69972   2.8
area2   23142   55587   2.4     NA
Total   48150   125559  2.61    NA 
DIS3                
        area1   16240   37173   2.29
area2   66351   193612  2.92    NA
Total   82591   230785  2.79    NA
```

and I want the data to look like this:

```
DIS1                
area1   69284   178198  2.57
area2    9466   22586   2.39    NA
Total    78750  200784  2.55    NA
DIS2                
area1   25008   69972   2.8
area2   23142   55587   2.4     NA
Total   48150   125559  2.61    NA 
DIS3                
area1   16240   37173   2.29
area2   66351   193612  2.92    NA
Total   82591   230785  2.79    NA
```

I am not sure how to go about writing some condition for this. So would be really grateful if someone could help me.

The dput looks like this:

```
 structure(list(a = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
 5L, 1L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("", "area2", "DIS1", "DIS2", "DIS3", 
"Total"), class = "factor"), b = structure(c(1L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 
 1L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("", "23142", "48150", 
 "66351", "78750", "82591", "9466", "area1"), class = "factor"), 
c = c(NA, 69284L, 22586L, 200784L, NA, 25008L, 55587L, 125559L, 
NA, 16240L, 193612L, 230785L), d = c(NA, 178198, 2.39, 2.55, 
NA, 69972, 2.4, 2.61, NA, 37173, 2.92, 2.79), e = c(NA, 2.57, 
NA, NA, NA, 2.8, NA, NA, NA, 2.29, NA, NA)), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you show the dput output of the above data i.e. `dput(DIS1)`

Comment: I have edited the question to show the dput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
as.data.frame( t(apply(DIS1, 1, function(x) 
            if(x[1]=='') c(x[-1], x[1]) else x)))
```